# Python cache on apache

Tags: python, apache

I am using python/Django on my apache server and I think there is a cache enable. When I modify settings.py I have to restart apache to see modifications.

How to disable cache? I am on DEBUG mode with Django.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html?

Comment: I disabled all cache module, and i still have a problem. When i modify a view.py, i have to restart wamp to see my modifications.

Comment: That's correct behavior.  What don't you like about it?

Comment: I don't want to restart my web server after each modification...

Comment: "I don't want to restart my web server" has **nothing** to do with this question.  Therefore, do the following.  (1) Search SO for ways to manage this.  It's probably been asked.  (2) Read the mod_wsgi documentation very carefully.  I'm very, very sure it's covered in there. (3) open a **new** question that has your **real** problem in it.